# Format 2 dates in 1 cell

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, date-formatting

I'm displaying 2 dates in 1 cell and I want to change the format of the 2 dates. I could do it with only one date but when it comes to 2 I struggle. here is a screenshot of my ag-grid: 
[image: Interface]

I tried to create new function dateFormatterr which takes 2 parameters and use it in columnDefs but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Grid, GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { DealsService } from './services/deals.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  gridOptions = {
    rowHeight: 70
  }
  columnDefs = [{
      headerName: "Block \n Deal",
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.BLOCKID + '<br/>' + params.data.DEALID
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Class \n Type',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.DEALCLASS + '<br/>' + params.data.DEALTYPE
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Trade \n Start',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.TRADEDATE + '<br/>' + params.data.STARTDATE
      },
      valueFormatter: this.dateFormatterr('TRADEDATE', 'STARTDATE'),
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Folder \n Cpty',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.FOLDERSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.CPTYSHORTNAME
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'ShortName \n Name',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.INSTRSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.INSTRNAME
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Quantity \n Settl.Amt',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.QUANTITY + '<br/>' + params.data.SETTLEAMT
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Rate \n Fees',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.FLOATINGRATESSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.RENTSPREADFIXEDRATE
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Category \n Status',
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return params.data.DEALCAT + '<br/>' + params.data.WORKFLOWSTATE
      },
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'End',
      field: 'ENDDATE',
      valueFormatter: this.dateFormatter,
      width: 140,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true
    },
  ];
  rowData: any;
  constructor(private service: DealsService) {}
  dateFormatter(params) {
    return moment(params.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }
  dateFormatterr(params1, params2) {
    return moment(params1.value + params2.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getDealsList().subscribe(data => {
      this.rowData = data;
    });
  }
}
```

I hope to get your help.

Comment: Call `moment(...).format(...)` twice and concatenate in `dateFormatterr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a custom cell renderer component for Trade Start column.

1. Create an ag-grid custom cell render component implementing ICellRendererAngularComp
2. Add the DateCellRendererComponent as the cellRendererFramework in column definition of Trade Start column
3. Register the custom cell render component in your app module.

date-cell-renderer.component.html

```
<p>{{trDate}} <br />{{strtDate}}</p>
```

date-cell-renderer.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
    import * as moment from 'moment';

    @Component({
       selector: 'app-comment-cell-renderer',
       templateUrl: './comment-cell-renderer.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./comment-cell-renderer.component.scss']
    })
    export class DateCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
       params: any;
       trDate: string;
       strtDate: string;

       refresh(params: any): boolean {
            return false;
       }

       agInit(params: any): void {
            this.params = params;
            this.trDate = moment(params.data.TRADEDATE).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            this.strtDate = moment(params.data.STARTDATE).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
       }

       constructor() { }
   }
```

app.component.ts

```
columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Trade \n Start',
      cellRendererFramework: DateCellRendererComponent,
      width: 150,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true,
    }
];
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents(
      [ DateCellRendererComponent]
    )
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the *dateFormatterr* function must take **one** parameter not two, inside the function :

1. You have to separate the two dates String into two String using regex/pattern or a custom function.
2. Parse each string to a date format
3. Finally sum the two dates using moment and return it

I cannot give you the code; because your screenshot dont show all the date.